# COUNT inside CASE WHEN is causing Invalid Column error

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
select case 
         when COUNT(*)>0 THEN (select TOP 1 A.a1)
         else 'none'
       end
from A
where A.a1 > 10
order by A.a1
```

Code above is causing the following error:

> Column 'A.a1' is invalid in the select list because it is not
> contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

I could not understand why.

My intention is as follows: If there are rows where A.a1 is greater than 10, order them and take the top rows's a1 value. If there is no such row, select 'none'.

**EDIT:** It is a simplified version of the actual code that is going to be used in a subquery. So, I cannot use IF..ELSE statements.

Comment: Based on "cannot use IF..ELSE statements", my answer has been modified.  It satisfies the example given.

Comment: Have you thought of using `ISNULL` on the outer query?

Answer (score 0):

You have an aggregation query because you have `count(*)`.  These are tricky with subqueries.  Instead, you can use:

```
select (case when count(*) > 0 then A1.a1 else 'none'
        end)
from A left join
     (select top 1 A.a1) A1
     on 1 = 1
where A1.a1 > 10
```

The logic of this is a bit non-sensical.  I assume your actual query is more useful.

Comment: I am getting the following error when running this code sample: The multi-part identifier "A.a1" could not be bound.

Comment: "I assume your actual query is more useful.": Yes, I posted a simplified sample isolating the problem. This will be used as a subquery in an update statement.

Comment: @JohnL. . . . The `order by` is superfluous because the query can only return one row.

Answer (score 0):

RE:  *Column 'A.a1' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.*

COUNT(*) is an aggregation.  SQL Server expects all columns to be in a GROUP BY.

RE: *If there are rows where A.a1 is greater than 10, order them and take the top rows's a1 value. If there is no such row, select 'none'.*
RE: EDIT: It is a simplified version of the actual code that is going to be used in a subquery. So, I cannot use IF..ELSE statements.

- ORDER by a1 value and take TOP 1 == MAX(a1).
- Assuming a1 is int orfloat, then the value must be converted to
  varchar to handle the 'none' output.  LOWER works and requires less typing than CAST or CONVERT.

Code:

```
SELECT ISNULL(LOWER(MAX(a1)), 'none') FROM A WHERE A.a1 > 10
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try with the **UNION ALL** to solve your Issue. Below Code is for your ref.

```
DECLARE @T TABLE(ID INT,NAME VARCHAR(200))

INSERT INTO @T VALUES(11,'HAI')
INSERT INTO @T VALUES(12,'H')

SELECT * FROM @T

DECLARE @VAL INT=10

SELECT TOP 1 T.NAME
FROM @T T
WHERE T.ID>@VAL
UNION ALL
SELECT 'None'
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM @T WHERE ID>@VAL)
```